# How do i make the last div in a row overflow into the next row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 rows in my webpage using bootstraps grid. The first row has 3 divs of equal width while the next two rows have 2 divs of the same width left aligned. However, the last div of the first row is longer than the first two divs and I want it to overflow into the second row. How would I do this?

I have a link here of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVfGN.jpg

Comment: make the last div position absolute, otherwise I don't think this is possible

Answer (score 1):

You would have to separate the page in example "content-left, content-right". Bootstrap isn't supposed to be used to have rows overflow in to another. So if you give content-left a width of like 8, and content-right 4. That way you can have different heights and make it seem like it's overflowing

Comment: Nicely answered :) "If you are not showing us your code".

Answer (score 0):

Try this grid:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6"></div>
        <div class="col-6"></div>
        <div class="col-6"></div>
        <div class="col-6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```